# Is there an industry standard tool available which parses s3 files and loads them to database tables?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, parsing

I have text files of multiple content formats on s3 buckets.

The simplest format had delimited content as dhwon below:

```
Field1|field2|field3|field4
```

I would like to parse the above delimited file and load the content into a database table also having the same structure (field1, 2 etc).

Is there an industry standard tool available to do this parsing?

Will Amazon DMS (Database Management System help with this)? Because the DMS home page (https://aws.amazon.com/dms/) says:

"With AWS Database Migration Service, you can continuously replicate your data with high availability and consolidate databases into a petabyte-scale data warehouse by streaming data to Amazon Redshift and Amazon S3"

Comment: I would convert it to a .csv. A texteditor can search/replace | into , or ;. Rename the file to .csv. phpmyadmin and most other tools can now import it.

Comment: I would like to automate this flow. I would receive files on my s3 bucket every day. An industry standard tool would be good. Else I would have to write some lambda/step functions using Java code to automate this.

Comment: I'm afraid that asking for a software or service recommendation is off-topic for SuperUser. I provided you an alternative, but if that doesn't work, you may have to brush up on your google skills to find the tool you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve this; here is an AWS-specific way you can go about it: [Loading Data into an Amazon Aurora MySQL DB Cluster from Text Files in an Amazon S3 Bucket](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Integrating.LoadFromS3.html). There are many small steps to follow in order to make it work, but the key big-picture steps are:

1. Setup your [Aurora](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/CHAP_GettingStartedAurora.html) MySQL database, including [creating the table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32605166/10376320) that the data will be loaded into
2. Give Aurora access to S3
3. Grant Privileges to Load Data in Amazon Aurora MySQL
4. `Load data from s3` statement